# Bounced emails for hosted sites bounce to nobody at the server - how to configure to return to the hosted site

Tags: email, smtp, email-bounces

I am helping out with some Linux admin work. The server hosts several sites. The admin interface used is WHM.

When an email from one of the hosted sites bounces, the site is not notified - it just goes to nobody@server.

How can I configure this to go back to each sites contact?

The mail server is Courier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

courier is not actually the issue here, it sounds like your apache and php is setup in DSO (mod_php) mode which means apache and php run as the nobody user this means that by default if not set emails sent via php/the webserver will appear to come from nobody@server as thats the user that created the original email, there are really only 2 solutions here

make sure each site that sends emails is correctly configured to also send the reply-to header and set the from header during mail send, this way bounce messages will go to the correct place

use a different php mode like suphp or fcgid which will run the processes as each user and will then bounce back into there cpanel account - this will still need them to forward it from there cpanel default account to there own account but at least its going to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Are you able to elaborate - this is volunteering for a charity and their associated sites and I'm a .NET programmer, not a sysadmin... By reply to do you mean when each site actually sends the mail?

Comment: depending on what there site is built on there should be the ability to set the from email address, if not then its slightly more complex but in most cases adding something like `php_admin_value sendmail_path  "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@mydomain.com"` to the .htaccess file for that domain should work

Comment: Bounce messages use the _envelope_ not the _headers_, remember.  It is the _envelope sender_ that you need to alter here, not the `Reply-To:` or `From:` headers.